# I want create array from looping and count same values from that array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want create array from looping.

I have tried using `array_count_values()` for count the array element, but variable from looping not read as array.

it's my code

```
$var_from_loop = "true,true,true,false,false";
```

I expect the output of:

```
true = 3
false = 2
```

Comment: can you help me to change it to array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use explode ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) to convert the string to array by `,` and then use [array-count-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$var_from_loop = "true,true,true,false,false";
$arr = explode("," , $var_from_loop);
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/FHrqi

Comment: wait ... I've tried it and it didn't work. But now it working..
thank @dWinder

Answer (score 4):

**Steps for approach 1:**

1) You can first convert the string to array by [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by comma(`,`).

You will get the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => true // 1st true
    [1] => true // 2nd true
    [2] => true // 3rd true 
    [3] => false // 1st false
    [4] => false // 2nd false
)
```

2) You will get an array containing 3 `true` and 2 `false` values (elements).

3) Then count how many times a values comes in array using [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
<?php
$var_from_loop = "true,true,true,false,false";
$arr = explode(',', $var_from_loop);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [true] => 3
    [false] => 2
)
```

[Working example:](https://3v4l.org/3orAP)

**Steps for approach 2 (only 3 lines of code):**

You can even use [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
$var_from_loop = "true,true,true,false,false";
echo 'TRUE: '.substr_count($var_from_loop, 'true');
echo '<br/>FALSE: '.substr_count($var_from_loop, 'false');
```

**Output:**

```
TRUE: 3
FALSE: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use explode and array count function

```
$var_from_loop = "true,true,true,false,false";
print_r(array_count_values(explode(",",$var_from_loop)));
```

output:-

```
Array
(
    [true] => 3
    [false] => 2
)
```